# addEventListener to multiple elements, using Event Delegation (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-delegation

I'm trying to add an event to multiple elements. For now, I have this code and it works. But, *I want to use Event Delegation* and move the listener to the parent element (deck). I've tried so many solutions found here on Stack, but none of them it's working.
Question, which will be the best way to delegate the event?

**HTML**

```
<section class="deck">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front"></div>
        <div class="back">
            <img src="#" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front"></div>
        <div class="back">
            <img src="#" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
```

**JavaScript**

```
var card = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
var len = card.length;

for (let i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
    card[i].onclick = function () {
        this.classList.add("foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why event delegation from the parent?  Are you dynamically adding card elements later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple event delegation could look like this in your case:

```
var deck = document.querySelector(".deck");

deck.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var target = e.target

  if (target.classList.contains('card')) {
    target.classList.add('foo') 
  }
})
```

Note, this check `target.classList.contains('card')` is necessary so that you add class `foo` only to elements with class `.card`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var deck = document.querySelector('.deck');
deck.onclick = function(clickevent)
{
   if (clicked.target.closest('.card'))
      clickevent.target.closest('.card').classList.add('foo');
}
```

The element that is clicked (the target of the click event) might be the `img` for example. You want to add `foo` to the card element that is an ancestor of the target. The closest() method finds that element.